# Qwik event that triggers when the element is initialized

Tags: javascript, frontend, jsx, qwik, qwikjs

I want to get an element. The quickest way to do that seems to be through `event.target`. So I want an event that is triggered as soon as an element is initialized, and then never again

Something like this

```html
<div
onInit$={(e)=>{
  // do stuff with e.target
}}></div>
```

I've tried onLoad$ and onComplete$, niether of which did what you would expect them to.
Also onDomContentLoaded isnt a thing

Answer (score 0):

You could use useVisibleTask for triggering a function when the component is rendered in the client side

https://qwik.builder.io/docs/components/tasks/#usevisibletask